# При открытии сайта на Symfony выдаёт ошибку SymfonyRuntime

Tags: apache, symfony, composer

При первом запуске сайта на Symfony выдаёт ошибку:

> Argument 1 passed to
> Symfony\Component\Runtime\SymfonyRuntime::getRunner() must be an
> instance of Symfony\Component\Runtime\object or null, instance of
> App\Kernel given...

Создал проект на симфони через композер, всё что я в нём изменил - это прописал в .htaccess перенаправление на папку /public и *"platform-check": false* в composer.json, чтобы он не ругался на версию php. Всё. При первом запуске он должен показывать экран приветствия. Поиск ни в документации ни в интернете ничего не дал.

Мой index.php

```
use App\Kernel;

require_once dirname(__DIR__).'/vendor/autoload_runtime.php';

return function (array $context) {
    return new Kernel($context['APP_ENV'], (bool) $context['APP_DEBUG']);
};
```

Вставлял различные примеры из документации, например выдача Hello World

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

require_once dirname(__DIR__).'/vendor/autoload_runtime.php';

return function () {
    return new Response('Hello world');
};
```

Но получаю однотипные ошибки:

> Return value of
> Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::setStatusCode() must be an
> instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\object, instance of
> Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response returned

Comment: сдается мне, что дефолтный index.php у симфони выглядит по другому

Comment: у меня на локальном в точности такой же index.php, созданный из композера - запускается без проблем

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось, что на моём домене была устаревшая версия 7.1, а не 7.3. Нужно было просто обновить версию php, а не прописывать "platform-check": false